# How to get value of binded datagrid column in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid and
I am loading it from code behind

My question is how to get value of a binded column ?
Actually I need to get value of "col1" (which is "Sale_ID_ass" at that moment)to be able to use it in "IF" Clause

```
General_Data_grid.ItemsSource = context.BD_Payments_TBL.ToList();
 General_Data_grid.Columns.Clear(); 
 

var col1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
col1.Header = "Id";
col1.Binding = new Binding("Sale_Id_ass");
  
 int v = **(to get here col1 value)**
                   
 if (v == 1)
 {
  //make some formatting
 }
 General_Data_grid.Columns.Add(col1);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: As you are binding Sale_Id_ass, this property contains the value for each row of BD_Payments_TBL in this column. So what value are you looking for? It not really clear

Comment: Yes I am binding Sale_Id_ass, and It has value for each row.  And I am looking for for Sale_Id_ass value for each row, and depending on the value I will give some formatting to that

Comment: How can you get a value for each row since your column is not yet added to the data grid? What kind of formatting do you want to apply? Give some examples. Do you want to format the data grid cell in this column based on the value in this cell? What type of value is expected in your test? We can't answer without specifics.

Comment: Thanks for comment. For example for all Sale_IDs which are more than 10000 show as negative. With minus. For now I achived it by recreating collection and putting already negative value for that criteria in new collection. And then binding datagrid to new collection, but this is usind additional resourses which i want to avoid.

Comment: Ok, but you're not answering my questions, I can't help you.

Comment: @Emilius: If you want to style the cell based on the value of the property/column, you should create a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` in your XAML markup.

Comment: @mm8 Thanks for your comment, could you give me some examples?

Comment: @Yannick I am sorry,
1) How can you get a value for each row since your column is not yet added to the data grid?- Maybe from binding(i dont know)
2) What kind of formatting do you want to apply?  -  Make negative depending on value
3) Give some examples. - For example for all Sale_IDs which are more than 10000 show as negative. With minus. 
4) Do you want to format the data grid cell in this column based on the value in this cell?  - Lets say Yes, I need more but if I will see how to do for that cell I will proceed with other
5)What type of value is expected in your test? - data is int

Answer (score 0):

DataGridViewColumn objects have a Name and a HeaderTextproperty. The indexer in your example uses the column's Name property To get Value
U can Use this code

```
var v = General_Data_grid.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().First(c => c.OwningColumn.HeaderText == "col1").Value;  
 if (object.Equals(v , 1))
    {
        //make some formatting
    }
```

Comment: It gives error "dataGrid does not contain definition for cast" .(